# How to Solve var_dump($testArray) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, dump

What is the problem with the code below? What will it output? How can it be fixed?

```
$referenceTable = array();
$referenceTable['val1'] = array(1, 2);
 $referenceTable['val2'] = 3;
$referenceTable['val3'] = array(4, 5);

 $testArray = array();

 $testArray = array_merge($testArray, $referenceTable['val1']);
 var_dump($testArray);
 $testArray = array_merge($testArray, $referenceTable['val2']);
var_dump($testArray);
  $testArray = array_merge($testArray, $referenceTable['val3']);
   var_dump($testArray);
```

Thanks

Comment: You have to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: what you mean? you want the output right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output will be as follows:

`array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) }
NULL
NULL`

You may also see two warnings generated, similar to the following:

`Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array`

`Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array`.

The issue here is that, if either the first or second argument to `array_merge()` is not an `array`, the return value will be NULL. For example, although one might reasonably expect that a call such as `array_merge($someValidArray, NULL)`would simply return `$someValidArray`, it instead returns `NULL`! (And to make matters worse, this is not documented well at all in the PHP documentation.)

As a result, the call to 
`$testArray = array_merge($testArray, $referenceTable['val2'])` 
evaluates to `$testArray = array_merge($testArray, 3)`and, since 3 is not of type array, this call to array_merge() returns NULL, which in turn ends up setting `$testArray` equal to NULL. Then, when we get to the next call to array_merge(), `$testArray` is now NULL so array_merge() again returns NULL. (This also explains why the first warning complains about argument #2 and the second warning complains about argument #1.)

The fix for this is straightforward. If we simply typecast the second argument to an array, we will get the desired results.

Comment: @condition0 Its very simple, `array_merge()` can only merge arrays. If one of the parameters is not an array, it does not convert automatically, it will simply fail. To append elements to an array, use `array_push()` instead.